# Python Django : Creating file object in memory without actually creating a file

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have an endpoint where I want to collect the response data and dump it into a file on S3 like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18731115/4824482

This is how I was trying to do it -

```
file_obj = open('/some/path/log.csv', 'w+')
file_obj.write(request.POST['data'])
```

and then passing `file_obj` to the S3 related code as in the above link.

The problem is that I don't have permissions to create a file on the server. Is there any way I can create a file object just in memory and then pass it to the S3 code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that's duplicate question of [How to upload a file to S3 without creating a temporary local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570465/how-to-upload-a-file-to-s3-without-creating-a-temporary-local-file). You would find best suggestion by checking out answers to that question.

**Shortly** the answer is code below:

```
from boto.s3.key import Key
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'yourkey'
k.set_contents_from_string(request.POST['data'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try tempfile https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

```
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
f.write(request.POST['data'])
```